# ¿Proyecto is not iterable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Bueno tengo mi state "serie" pero esta viene como array a lo que yo vengo y le aplico array destructuring
para poder acceder a la posicion de la serie en el state y me marca un error de `serie is not iterable`, pero si es un array como que no lo puede iterar, que dices...  Luego aplique `object.keys` y seguía marcado error. Me podrían ayudar por favor

```js
import React, { Fragment, useContext } from 'react';
import Capitulo from './Capitulos';
import SeriesContext from '../../context/proyecto/seriesContext';
const ListadoCapitulos = () => {

    //extraer state
    const seriesContext = useContext(seriesContext);
    const { serie } = seriesContext;

    //si no hay proyecto seleccionado
    if(!serie) return null;

    const [serieActual] = serie;

    const capitulosSerie = [
        {
            nombre: 'CSI capitulo 1',
        },
        {
            nombre: 'CSI capitulo 2',
        }
    ]


    
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className="col-md-12">
                <div className="listado-capitulo">
                    <h2>Serie: {serieActual.nombre}</h2>

                    {capitulosSerie.length === 0
                        ? (<h1>No hay capitulos</h1>)
                        : capitulosSerie.map(capitulo =>
                            <Capitulo
                                capitulo={capitulo}
                            />
                        )
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="eliminar-serie">
                <button className="btn btn-dark">Eliminar serie</button>
            </div>

        </Fragment>

    );
}

export default ListadoCapitulos;
```

Comment: En la linea `if(!serie) return null;`, intenta reemplazarlo por `if (!serie) {return null;}`. Saludos.

Comment: lo intenté y no funcionó, pero igual la sintaxis es valida, el problema radica en el array destructuring... Incluso lo imprimo en consola y me marca que es array cuando intento agregar una serie, o sea, añadir otro objeto al array proyectos se explota. cabe mencionar que en mi state tengo: proyectos: [{},{},{}....{}], proyecto: null.... cuando selecciono un componente le paso el state y cambia a: proyectos: [{},{},{}....{}], proyecto: [{}].... pero cuando lo extraigo del context y le aplico destructuring me tira un array is not iterable al combinarlo con agregar otro objeto al "proyectos".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`payload: action.payload` este era el problema lo que modificaba mi state, luego de esto cuando tenia seleccionado un componente e intentaba agregar uno nuevo, inmediatamente en mi state dejaba de ser un array se convertia en un objeto lo que no me permitia iterarlo al no contar con las propiedades.

```js
import { 
    FORMULARIO_PROYECTO,
    OBTENER_PROYECTO,
    AGREGAR_PROYECTO,
    PROYECTO_ACTUAL,
    VALIDAR_FORMULARIO,
    ELIMINAR_PROYECTO
 } from '../../types';

export default(state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FORMULARIO_PROYECTO: 
            return {
                ...state,
                formulario: true 
            }
        case AGREGAR_PROYECTO:
            return {
                ...state,
                proyectos: [...state.proyectos, action.payload],
                formulario: false,
                errorFormulario: false,
                //payload: action.payload 
            }
        case VALIDAR_FORMULARIO:
            return {
                ...state,
                errorFormulario: true
            }
        case PROYECTO_ACTUAL:
            return {
                ...state,
                proyecto: state.proyectos.filter(proyecto => proyecto.id === 
                    action.payload)
            }
        case OBTENER_PROYECTO:
            return {
                ...state,
                formulario: false,
                proyectos: action.payload
            }
        case ELIMINAR_PROYECTO:
            return {
                ...state,
                proyectos: state.proyectos.filter(proyecto => proyecto._id !== action.payload),
                proyecto: null
            }
        default:
            return state;

    }
}
```